# How to control line height between non block level elements with different font sizes?

Tags: layout, css

I have a layout where I need to control the line height between wrapped non block level elements:

`<p class="payments"><small class="light">You Pay</small><abbr title="GBP">£</abbr>121.50<br><small>per month</small></p>`

What I want to achieve is something like:

[image: Example]

I don't want to rely on absolute positioning as there will be elements beneath which need to clear this and simply setting a low line-height on he paragraph results in an object which breaks out of its box, see the Fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/mdHKy/2/

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi can u used to position relative and absolute for this solution may be ...........

Comment: Thanks Rohit, that actually worked out very well. Position absolute on the children and position relative on the parent, I then added a corresponding margin-bottom equal to the font-size of the small text elements to maintain the spacing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first give the `p` a `height` then set its `line-height` to half that amount (being 2 lines).

```
p.payments {
    line-height: 1em;
    height:2em;
}
```

Then set the `line-height` of `small` to `1em` and give that a `vertical-align`:

```
p.payments small {
    line-height:1em;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Then set the `vertical-align` of your `.light`:

```
p.payments small.light {
    vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mdHKy/3/).